# Why is alpinejs @click handler calling my console.log twice

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am wondering why this html / alpinejs is generating multiple console log entries when the button is clicked.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ }">
  <button @click="console.log('Click!')">Click it!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Alpine.js docs](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation#from-a-script-tag) you are missing the [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) when adding the script. Adding that in will solve your problem.

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ }">
  <button @click="console.log('Click!')">Click it!</button>
</div>
```